# O union (mySQL) pode ser usado também em Updates?

Tags: php, mysql

Exemplo :

```
$query = "update tabela set coluna1 = 1 where id = {$id_m} union
          update tabela set coluna2 = 1 where id = {$id_v}";
```

Answer (score 1):

> UNION is used to combine the result from multiple SELECT statements
>   into a single result set.
>   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

A princípio é utilizado só em SELECT.

Comment: Tem alguma maneira de eu alterar dados de diferentes colunas mas deixando isso em uma só query?

Comment: tente: 
 $query = "update tabela set coluna1 = 1 where id = {$id_m}; update tabela set coluna2 = 1 where id = {$id_v}";

Comment: Retornou um erro de sintaxe para o segundo update...

Comment: aqui eu consegui


    $sql = 'update categoria set nome=? where id=?; update categoria set nome=? where id=?';
    $bindings =  array('abc',1, 'cba',2);
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $result = $stmt->execute($bindings);
    echo $result; //true